# Intercepting context.SaveChanges() in MVC 3 so that I can modify and use a custom sql query instead

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am working on an MVC3 project whose model is designed using Code First approach. I am using EF4 for ORM and have a need where I need two thing - 
1. Intercept the context.SaveChages method 
2.Do my own custom update query for one specific entity type only.

I got the first part working by overriding the SaveChanges() method like -

```
    public  override  int SaveChanges()
    { 
var modifiedItems = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == System.Data.EntityState.Modified && e.Entity is myEntityName);
        foreach (var item in modifiedItems)
        {
           //ToDo: Write UPDATE Sql Query here
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

How can I write my update query? 
Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to write your update query?  As SQL? Using a different ORM? However you do it, ensure you clear the modified items of <yourType> from the context prior to saving changes or the context will overwrite anything you've done.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can only [map custom stored procedures](http://thedatafarm.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/using-stored-procedures-for-insert-update-amp-delete-in-an-entity-data-model/) to be used instead of CUD operations (only with EDMX) generated by EF but still you will have single stored procedure call per each operation and entity instance.